# How do I echo Nested Array Element?

Tags: php, json, loops, multidimensional-array, nested

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I can't get my array item to echo out. I keep getting this error:

> Illegal string offset 'CreatedDatetime'.

My XML looks like this via JSON `print_r`:

```
Array
(
[ABOUT_VERSIONS] => Array
    (
        [ABOUT_VERSION] => Array
            (
                [CreatedDatetime] => 2019-10-22T22:29:47.7617229Z
                [DataVersionIdentifier] => 201703
            )

    )
)
```

My code is:

```
foreach ($newArr["ABOUT_VERSIONS"]["ABOUT_VERSION"] as $item){
   echo $item["CreatedDatetime"]."<br>";
}
```

This seems so simple but I'm having a block. I can't echo out the `CreatedDatetime` key.

Comment: Can you share how $newArr is set? Also what XML are you talking about?

Comment: Can you post the output of var_dump($newArr) ?

Comment: The $newArr is an xml file that i converted to json. The file is 5000+ lines of code so i just shortened it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$item` is not an array, it iterates over the two values in `$newArr['ABOUT_VERSION']` i.e. `2019-10-22T22:29:47.7617229Z` and `201703`. To display the `CreatedDatetime`, either access it directly:

```
echo $newArr["ABOUT_VERSIONS"]["ABOUT_VERSION"]["CreatedDatetime"] . "<br>";
```

or do a key comparison in the loop:

```
foreach ($newArr["ABOUT_VERSIONS"]["ABOUT_VERSION"] as $key => $value){
   if ($key == "CreatedDatetime") echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

In both cases the output is `2019-10-22T22:29:47.7617229Z`.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/orL82)